# Inequality for sum of tangents and cotangents

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Let the function $f_k(x)$ be defined as 
\begin{align}
f_k(x)= \frac{k^2}{1-k}\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{1-k}\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)- (k-1) \tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right),
\end{align}
defined on $x \in (0,1)$.

I would like to show that $f_k(x)$ is positive for $k \in (0,1)$ and negative for $k \in (1,2)$ for all  $x \in (0,1)$.

I looked at the number of trig identities but not sure what would be a nice and clean way of showing that this inequality is true.

My numerical simulations support the statement of the inequality.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: what have tried?

Comment: Are you happy that $f_k \rightarrow \infty$ when $k \rightarrow 1^+$?

Comment: a plot Shows us that your Statement is not true.

Comment: @Bacon   Yes, it is not a problem for me.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Tried playing with trig identities for $\tan(a+b)$.    Strange, my simulation shows that my claim is correct.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I agree with OP, the plot does seem to show the statement is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I didn't make a mistake because last part took some time

$\begin{align}
f_k(x)= \frac{k^2}{1-k}\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\frac{1}{1-k}\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)- (k-1) \tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{1-k} \left[ k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)-(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\right],
\end{align}$

if $k∈(0,1) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-k}\gt0$

if $k∈(1,2) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-k}\lt0$

So,we should prove that $\left[ k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)-(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\right]\gt0$   in each case

$\qquad$(i)  if $k∈(0,1) $,

because $0\lt\ \frac{\pi k x}{2},\frac{\pi  x}{2},\frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2}\lt \pi/2 $

$k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)\gt0$ and

$\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)\gt\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\gt(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)$

(Because $tan(x)$ is monotone increasing when $x\in (0,1)$ )

$\Rightarrow \tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)-(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\gt0$

$\Rightarrow k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)-(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\gt0$

$\qquad$(ii)  if $k∈(1,2)$

$\left[ k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)-(1-k)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (1-k)}{2} \right)\right]=\left[ k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)+(k-1)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right]$

$0\lt\ \frac{\pi  x}{2},\frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2}\lt \pi/2 $

if  $x\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$,

then  $0\lt\ \frac{\pi k  x}{2}\lt \pi/2 $

$cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2}\right),\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right),\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\gt0$

$\Rightarrow  k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)+(k-1)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\gt0$

if  $x\gt\dfrac{1}{2}$,

then  there is possibility that $\pi/2 \lt\ \frac{\pi k  x}{2}\lt \pi $ and so

$cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2}\right)\lt0$

Lastly, we should analyze this case:

I'm gonna use Cauchy's inequality

$\left [\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2} \right)+(k-1)^2\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right]\left [\dfrac {1}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)}+\dfrac {1}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)} \right]\geq(1+(k-1))^2=k^2$

$\Rightarrow\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2} \right)+(k-1)^2\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\geq k^2 \dfrac {\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)+\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)}$

And by using $\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)=\dfrac {\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)+\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)}{1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)}$

(If $\frac {\pi  x k}{2}=\frac {\pi}{2}$, then $\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)=\infty$ which would be a problem but it's nothing to worry about because it gives $\cot\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)=\cot(\frac {\pi}{2})=0$)

$\Rightarrow tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)+\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)=\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\left( 1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right)$

We will get

$\Rightarrow  k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x}{2} \right)+(k-1)^2\tan\left( \frac{\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\geq$

$  k^2\cot\left( \frac{\pi k x}{2} \right)+k^2 \dfrac {\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\left( 1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right)}$

$=k^2\dfrac {\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)+\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\cot\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\left( 1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right)}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\left( 1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right)}$

$=k^2\dfrac {1}{\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x k}{2}\right)\left( 1-\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x}{2}\right)\tan\left( \frac {\pi  x (k-1)}{2} \right)\right)}\gt0$